# Visual Studio: Condition "if (InDesigner)"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

This question bugs me since a long time: 
**Can I have a condition that is true if the Visual Studio designer is executing it, and false otherwise?**

**For example** (WPF), I want to use a special BoolToVisibilityConverter to bind the visibility property of some controls to the mouse being over that control. I do this with the following XAML code:

```
<Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="../Images/MB_0010_tasks.ico" Margin="12,133,133,12" MouseLeftButtonUp="Image_MouseLeftButtonUp" 
          Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=IsMouseOver, Converter={StaticResource __boolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

This leads to the elements not being visible in Visual Studio's designer view. Is there a way to tell the Converter something like this:

```
#if DESIGNER
return Visibility.Visible;
#endif
return b ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode()` method:

```
// In WPF:
var isDesign = DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(Application.Current.MainWindow);

// In Silverlight:
var isDesign = DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(Application.Current.RootVisual);

if(isDesign)
{
    // designer code
    return;
}

// non designer code
```

In either Blend or Visual Studio (I'm not sure which one it was) this will always be false, so you should also include the following check:

```
isDesign = isDesign || Application.Current.GetType().Equals(typeof(Application));
```

This works because in the running program `Application.Current` will always be your own derived Application class (by default: `App`, defined in App.xaml and App.xaml.cs respectively)

Comment: Works like a charm, especially in my BoolToVisibilityConverters. Thanks a lot!

Comment: +1! Finally, something that works! GetIsInDesignMode started to return false but your last check did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For a WPF application you could try something like the following:

```
        if ((bool)(DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(DependencyObject)).DefaultValue))
        {
            // If we're here it's the design mode
        }
```